# '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Following is my code of reading a CSV file but got error what's wrong with my code.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(img_category_path, delim_whitespace= True,  header=0, names=['category'], low_memory=False )


df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  i < 21 else '3' if   i > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]
```

while i add `low_memory= False` still getting error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-e50367d03a63> in <module>
----> 1 df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  i < 21 else '3' if   i > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]

<ipython-input-146-e50367d03a63> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  i < 21 else '3' if   i > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

df2 = pd.read_csv(img_category_path, delim_whitespace= True,  header=0, names=['category'], low_memory=False )

df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  i < 21 else '3' if   i > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]
```

filtering the file to get exact result

Comment: One Object is a `str` and one object is an `int`. Convert the `str` object to an `int` object with `int(<>)` and you can use the `<` operator.

Comment: 'You can't compare instances of str and int' describes precisely what is wrong with your code. Try checking the type of the `I` variable

Comment: As a token of appreciation of the person answering your question you are encouraged to mark a solution to your problem as the answer to the question using the tick mark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your issue by changing:

```
df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  i < 21 else '3' if   i > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]
```

to:

```
df['upper_lower'] = ['1' if  int(i) < 21 else '3' if int(i) > 36  else  '2' for i in df2['category']]
```

The problem arises (as pointed out in the comments) because you loaded strings representing numbers from your CSV file and you need to convert them to `int` before comparison (your `i` variable and `df2["category"]` Series are of type `str`.

Comment: didn't work showing following error        (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'category_label'
)